How did you support email forwarding in your past or current orgs with E2C set up?
Issue: E2C set up for Queue A receives email and creates Case. Email is forwarded to another address with E2C set up for Queue B but remains in Queue A.
How did you support email forwarding in your past or current orgs with E2C set up for multiple queues working on a single Case?
Thanks in advance for your time reviewing my post.
Nic
Related post

Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. Please note that we ask that posters not include TIA (Thanks In Advance). Aside from that, what's the end goal here? It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. This may be an X-Y Problem. You can [edit] your question to include relevant background information that may help us come up with an appropriate solution.
